# connection to vxworks simulator in workbench 3.0

Tags: vxworks

I am trying to create a connection to Vxworks simulator from workbench 3.0 with help of document

http://read.pudn.com/downloads150/ebook/651613/wr_workbench_vxworks_tutorials_3.0.pdf

Here in section 3.5 it is mentioned as below

1. To create a new target connection definition, click the Define a connection to remote system icon on the Remote Systems view toolbar, or right-click in the Remote Systems view and select New Connection.
2. In the New Connection wizard, select VxWorks 6.x > Wind River VxWorks 6.x Simulator Connection, then click Next.
3. Click Finish to accept all of the default configuration settings and create your connection definition.5 Because the Immediately connect to target if possible box is selected by default, Workbench attempts to connect to the simulator.

My question in my machine  when I select new connection I am seeing following options in wizard

1. General, FTP Only, Linux, Local, SSH Only, Unix, and Windows. But not VxWorks 6.x. What is mistake I have done or what are the steps I have to follow?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a license enabling vxworks in workbench, the entries won't show up.